# Get the text the user wrote on a text box, and show it in another div with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, text

I am a newbie in jQuery. I have a simple form wrapped with this code:

```
<div class="search_container"> 
    <form action="mode" onSubmit="calcRoute();return false;" id="routeForm">
          <input type="text" id="routeStart" PlaceHolder="Pikënisja" ><br/>
          <input type="text" id="routeEnd" class="routeEnd" PlaceHolder="Destinacioni">
        <button id="submit"><i class="icon-map-marker"></i></button>
    </form>
</div>
```

I want something like this:

When somebody fills in the text boxes, and clicks the submit button, the text he put in the textboxes will be posted in another div.

Ex. In the first text box I write "New York", and in the second one, I put "Florida".

In a div under the form, I get this result:

The first text (In this case New York), the second text (in this case Florida).

I hope somebody can help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
$('#submit').click(function(e){
    // prevents the form's submission
    e.preventDefault();
    $('selector').text($('#routeStart').val()); // sets the text of the element 
    $('otherSelector').text($('#routeEnd').val()); // to the value of the input
});
```

Assuming the elements into which you want to insert the text has a predictable suffix (for example 'txt'), and a class, the above can be made more scalable using the following:

```
<div class="search_container"> 
    <form action="mode" onSubmit="calcRoute();return false;" id="routeForm">
          <input type="text" id="routeStart" PlaceHolder="Pikënisja" ><br/>
          <input type="text" id="routeEnd" class="routeEnd" PlaceHolder="Destinacioni">
        <button id="submit"><i class="icon-map-marker"></i></button>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="waypoints" id="routeStartTxt"></div>
<div class="waypoints" id="routeEndTxt"></div>
```

And the jQuery:

```
$('#submit').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // prevents form-submission
    $('.waypoints').text(function(){ // iterates over each of the .waypoints elements
        /* finds the element whose id matches the id of the current .waypoint element,
           *without* the 'Txt' suffix, and sets the text of the current .waypoint to 
           be the value found in that element. */
        $('#' + this.id.replace('Txt','')).val();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to put the text from an input and place in another div:

HTML:

```
<div id="routeStartTxt"></div>
```

JS:

```
$('#submit').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $('#routeStartTxt').html($('#routeStart').val());
   // do the other inputs here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's `.val()` method to get the **value** of a text box. You can then use the `.html()` method to set the html of another element.

```
value = $('input').val();
$('div').html(value);
```

or as a one liner

```
$('div').html($('input').val());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Add a new div:

```
<div id="route"></div>
```

JS:

```
$('#submit').click(function (e) {

    // 1. First prevent the default action of button click
    e.preventDefault();

    // 2. Get the textbox values and trim it
    var routeStart = $.trim($('#routeStart').val());
    var routeEnd = $.trim($('#routeEnd').val());

    // 3. Check it the values are not empty
    if (routeStart == '' || routeStart == '') 
        $('#route').html('Please enter some text!');
    else 
        $('#route').html(routeStart + '  ' + routeEnd);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="search_container"> 
    <form action="mode" onSubmit="calcRoute();return false;" id="routeForm">
        <input type="text" id="routeStart" PlaceHolder="Pikënisja" /><br/>
        <input type="text" id="routeEnd" class="routeEnd" PlaceHolder="Destinacioni" />
        <button id="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>

<div id="append"></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("form#routeForm").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var firstVal = $("#routeStart").val();
    var SecondVal = $("#routeEnd").val();

    $("#append").append("<p>" + firstVal + " " + SecondVal + "</p>");

});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XcANe/)**